# How to connect Google Cloud PostgreSQL with C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I created a managed sql instance on Google Cloud using these [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart).

I would like to connect from my code using C#.

When I write locally, this is my connection string:

```
public string LocalDataSource = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\versionsOfMediaPlayer\14.4.19\mediaPlayer_1\Database1.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
```

and I manage to write to local sql.

What should be my connection string for the instance on Google Cloud?

details of my instance:

```
ip: <MY_IP_ADDRESS>
user: postgres
password: postgres
Instance connection name: my-project:us-central1:my-sql-instance
```

I added my local ip to the Cloud SQL instance firewall - so I manage to connect via command line, now I'd like to do so programmatically, using C#.
what should be my connection string?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have [authorized](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ip) your IP address to connect, connecting to Cloud SQL is the same as any other database. According the the MySQL Connector docs for C# (found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-connection-string.html)), the connection string should look like the following:

```
"server=<YOUR_IP_ADDRESS>;uid=postgres;pwd=postgres;database=your-database";
```